# Paging works Sorting fails ASP.NET Gridview control bould to IList

Tags: asp.net, gridview

ASPX page:
-Gridview Control as shown below

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gidtest" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White"
        BorderColor="#CC9966" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" Width="100%"
        AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" 
        OnPageIndexChanging="gidtest_PageIndexChanging" OnSorting="gidtest_Sorting">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="MinistryName" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="MinistryName"
                ItemStyle-Width="40%" >
<ItemStyle Width="40%"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:BoundField>
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" ForeColor="#330099" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#FFFFCC" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" ForeColor="#330099" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <PagerSettings FirstPageText="first" LastPageText="last" Mode="NumericFirstLast" PageButtonCount="2"/>
        <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#330099" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#663399" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FEFCEB" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#AF0101" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#F6F0C0" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#7E0000" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

Code behind:
-On Page load assinging a List to Gridview.
-On Paging event rebinding the list.

---

### -On Sorting event trying to Get DataSource but NULL is returned

---

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {

            this.gridProjects.DataSource = GetList(); //A IList collection of BOL, which has MinistryName proeprty.
        this.gridProjects.DataBind();
    }
    ////Log before exiting from the Function.
    WebRole.Logger.Write(Page.Title.ToString() + Resources.ExitPageLoad);
}

    GetList()
    {
    return new List<CustomClass>();
    }

    public Class CustomClass
    {
    public string MinistryName {get;set;}
    }



     protected void gidtest_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e != null)
        {
            this.GetUserProjects();
            this.gridProjects.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            this.gridProjects.DataBind();
        }
    }

     protected void gridProjects_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
           DataTable dt =((DataSet)(gridProjects.DataSource)).Tables[0];
           dt.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression +"" + e.SortDirection;

           gridProjects.DataSource = dt;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }

    }
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add space between `e.SortExpression` and `e.SortDirection`
2. Add `this.gridProjects.DataBind();` after `gridProjects.DataSource = dt;`

Try this:

```
protected void gridProjects_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
  try
    {
       DataTable dt =((DataSet)(gridProjects.DataSource)).Tables[0];
       dt.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + e.SortDirection;

       gridProjects.DataSource = dt;
       this.gridProjects.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The datasource is not returned on postback,  your going to need to get the data again.

Your using a list of objects so you may need to implement a Generic List Sort like described **[here](http://paigecsharp.blogspot.com/2007/07/generic-list-sorting.html)**, unless you can order the list when it gets built.

```
protected void gridProjects_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{


     List<CustomClass> lst = GetList();

     if (e.SortDirection == "Ascending"){
          lst.Sort(new GenericComparer<CustomClass>(e.SortExpression,SortDirection.Ascending);
     }else{
          lst.Sort(new GenericComparer<CustomClass>(e.SortExpression,SortDirection.Descending);
     }

     gridProjects.DataSource = lst;
     gridProjects.DataBind();
}
```